# How does MSBuild resolve dotnet SDKs?

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

There are various .NET SDKs for SDK-style projects in the *C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\<dotnet version>\Sdks* folder. I am trying to understand how MSBuild resolves these SDKs given that the dotnet installation appears to be somewhat independent from the [MSBuild project](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/) in this regard. That is, the MSBuild project only contains a [DefaultSdkResolver](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/8da5fc70969354a2849e4dcec20cf59b98f4d2c3/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/SdkResolution/DefaultSdkResolver.cs) which resolves SDKs inside the MSBuild folder. But nothing about dotnet.

The question is how does MSBuild know about the SDKs in the dotnet folder and how does it know about the additional SdkResolvers found in *dotnet\sdk\<dotnet version>\SdkResolvers*?

Yes, it is an implementation detail. But I am keen to know how exactly these almost magical SDK-style projects work. Magic because additional targets and properties are hidden behind some Sdk attribute in a .csproj file.

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look at "[How project SDKs are resolved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk?view=vs-2022#how-project-sdks-are-resolved)". Also take a look at the [microsoft/MSBuildSdks](https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildSdks) repo.